# Struts2 <s:url> / <s:param> tags outputting date parameter values that fail in type conversion

Tags: struts2, tags

I'm struggling with a Struts2 date formatting issue. If I understand correctly, type conversion in Struts2 is locale aware, and any form fields/parameters that map to Date objects should be strings formatted in their Locale specific SHORT format; the default output for a Date object on the value stack is also output as the Locale specific SHORT format (unless overridden with custom formatting).

Although form fields have worked fine with dates, when using the `<s:url>` tag I can't seem to get the `<s:param>` tag to encode date parameters correctly. When I try something such as this

```
<s:url action="foo" >
  <s:param name="endDateParam" value="#endDate"/>
</s:url>
```

the result is pretty obviously not the SHORT format:

```
/foo.action?endDateParam=Sat+Jan+14+00%3A00%3A00+EST+2012
```

I re-read the Struts2 documentation but they mostly discuss creating custom date formats in the i18n'ized properties files, which doesn't seem like the right solution.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can send it like that :

```
<s:param name="dateFrom">
<s:date name="dateFrom" format="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
</s:param>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already solved this by formatting a string in the action the way you need it. This I would advise first, unless you are supper stickler for model/view separation or there isn't a one to one mapping between the action and the view in which case this zealousness my be justified.

Lets say you felt the formatting wasn't the business of the action in that case you could use OGNL to it's full effect:

Here is an example that displays the current date (it uses *new* to construct a new date but you can very easily just replace "new java.util.Date()" with "endDate". It was constructed this way so anyone can just paste it into their JSP without any action dependencies.

```
<p>
   <s:property value="@java.text.DateFormat@getDateInstance(@java.text.DateFormat@SHORT, @java.util.Locale@CANADA).format(new java.util.Date())"/>
</p>
```

**NOTE**: requires OGNL static method access to be true. Easiest way to do that is to add the following to struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

Using OGNL to this level is a bit suspicious but it is easy to read and the intention is clearly view/presentation related. Although it isn't that easy to construct... The easiest way is to write everything as one line of java and then apply ognl syntax rules which you would find here:

http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html

Also for quick reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html